# Duvida se está certo meu código em Assembly

Tags: assembly

Boa noite, estou começando a estudar assembly e tenho dúvidas sobre o exercício que estou resolvendo. O primeiro estou tentando criar uma seção de variáveis nao inicializadas, e as inicializadas e fazer as seguintes cópias
n1 = v1
n2 = v2
n3 = v3
fiz este código, gostaria de ver se está realmente certo o que eu fiz ou se tem possível melhoras, usar algum outro registrador

```
section .data
    v1: db 10d 
    v2: dd -20d
    v3: dq -30d

section .bss
    n1: resb 1
    n2: resw 2
    n3: resd 4

  section .text
  global _start

  _start:
mov al   , [v1]
mov [n1] , al
mov ebx  , [v2] 
mov [n2] , ebx
mov al   , [v3] 
mov [n3] , al

fim:
mov rax, 1
mov rbx, 0
int 0x80
```

Comment: então o MOV não se passa de memória diretamente para memória em Assembly :/ é necessário usar um registrador